# What kind of lens do I need to cast a crisp shadow on a far wall?

Tags: optics, lenses

I'm trying to build a hand held toy that should cast a shadow of an animal on a wall. Imagine a flashlight that you cover with some plastic shaped like a dog.

The "flashlight" is relatively small, so the distance from the led to the cover (the dog silhouette) is about 5-10 cm while the wall is a few meters away. I get a very blurry shadow. Much more than I want (I obviously want it to be large, but more crisp even if not 100%). What kind of lens do I need to solve this? Does it have to be from a specific material? (will plastic also work?) Where should it be placed?

Comment: You want a slide projector.

Answer (score 1):

As mmesser314 says, what you're trying to do is *project an image*. For that, you need a lens between the object and the target. A lens designed for a slide projector would probably be a good choice.

Comment: It seems to me OP wants to project a shadow rather than an image.

Comment: that's right. doesn't have to be an image, just blocking some of the light is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what's happening is you're getting an indistinct shadow because of the width of the beam of light from the flashlight. Do you know about the umbra and penumbra parts of a shadow?

Try putting a black cover sheet over the flashlight with a small round opening at its center to create a smaller source.

Comment: If a very faint projected shadow is OK, this will work.